# How to estimate/predict data size and index size of a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, index, innodb

I am finding **what is the best way to estimate size of a table** for that I have studied lot of blogs and forums but unable to find any accurate answer

For example, we have a **table City with InnoDB engine**,lets say in future (in next 1 year) it will have 1 million of records so what will be the estimated data size and index size of that table in this period.

```
mysql> desc City;
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID          | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name        | char(35) | NO   |     |         |                |
| CountryCode | char(3)  | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| District    | char(20) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Population  | int(11)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

What will be the estimated upper bound (Max size of table) with 1 million records and how can we estimate it.

Comment: This is great. but is it possible to get the index size column wise. What is mean is if you have a table with (say) 5 columns indexed. Can we get the index size of each one of them? I will ask this as another question. thanks

Answer (score 68):

Given the table description, I see

- 66 bytes per row of data
- 4 bytes per row for the primary key
- 7 bytes per row for country code index

  - 3 bytes for the country
  - 4 bytes for Clustered Key attached to the country code
- Total of 77 bytes of data and keys
- This does not factoring housekeeping for BTREEs or Tablespace Fragmentation

For a million rows, that would 77,000,000 bytes (73.43 MB)

As for measuring the table, for a given table mydb.mytable, you can run this query

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(FORMAT(DAT/POWER(1024,pw1),2),' ',SUBSTR(units,pw1*2+1,2)) DATSIZE,
    CONCAT(FORMAT(NDX/POWER(1024,pw2),2),' ',SUBSTR(units,pw2*2+1,2)) NDXSIZE,
    CONCAT(FORMAT(TBL/POWER(1024,pw3),2),' ',SUBSTR(units,pw3*2+1,2)) TBLSIZE
FROM
(
    SELECT DAT,NDX,TBL,IF(px>4,4,px) pw1,IF(py>4,4,py) pw2,IF(pz>4,4,pz) pw3
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT data_length DAT,index_length NDX,data_length+index_length TBL,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(data_length=0,1,data_length))/LOG(1024)) px,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(index_length=0,1,index_length))/LOG(1024)) py,
        FLOOR(LOG(data_length+index_length)/LOG(1024)) pz
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema='mydb'
        AND table_name='mytable'
    ) AA
) A,(SELECT 'B KBMBGBTB' units) B;
```

To measure all tables grouped by Database and Storage Engine

```
SELECT
    IF(ISNULL(DB)+ISNULL(ENGINE)=2,'Database Total',
    CONCAT(DB,' ',IFNULL(ENGINE,'Total'))) "Reported Statistic",
    LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(DAT/POWER(1024,pw1),2),' ',
    SUBSTR(units,pw1*2+1,2)),17,' ') "Data Size",
    LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(NDX/POWER(1024,pw2),2),' ',
    SUBSTR(units,pw2*2+1,2)),17,' ') "Index Size",
    LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(TBL/POWER(1024,pw3),2),' ',
    SUBSTR(units,pw3*2+1,2)),17,' ') "Total Size"
FROM
(
    SELECT DB,ENGINE,DAT,NDX,TBL,
    IF(px>4,4,px) pw1,IF(py>4,4,py) pw2,IF(pz>4,4,pz) pw3
    FROM 
    (SELECT *,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(DAT=0,1,DAT))/LOG(1024)) px,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(NDX=0,1,NDX))/LOG(1024)) py,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(TBL=0,1,TBL))/LOG(1024)) pz
    FROM
    (SELECT
        DB,ENGINE,
        SUM(data_length) DAT,
        SUM(index_length) NDX,
        SUM(data_length+index_length) TBL
    FROM
    (
       SELECT table_schema DB,ENGINE,data_length,index_length FROM
       information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN
       ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql')
       AND ENGINE IS NOT NULL
    ) AAA GROUP BY DB,ENGINE WITH ROLLUP
) AAA) AA) A,(SELECT ' BKBMBGBTB' units) B;
```

Run these queries and you can track changes in database/engine disk usage.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: The `CHAR` lengths need to be multiplied by 3 if you have `CHARSET utf8`.  The entire overhead can be estimated by doubling or tripling the computation.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA , do you know if is possible to calculate the "real" row size of a table with the objective to compare with the real size (compressed table) and get the ratio of compress?

Comment: @ceinmart  innodb_page_size is fixed (16K or 16384 by default) and becomes the boundary where rows and grouped or split. Changing innodb_page_size can alter storage of data for good or bad.Based on the how filled or sparse a row is (especially with the presence of TEXT/BLOB/VARCHAR). At best, you should compare the the size of .ibd file to what the schema report to estimate a ratio. You may also need to perform a NULL ALTER TABLE (`ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=InnoDB;`)to get an accurate ratio. Effort may not be worth it.

Comment: @ceinmart Keep in mind hat changing innodb_page_size is not a table-by-table setting. You would need to do a full export of the data (See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/how-to-change-innodb_page_size/)

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: Any idea how to know amount of data added to all tables of a database daily based on certain column like `created_at` ? Will be useful for telling beforehead when to add more capacity to server once we know how much data amount is added daily.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using InnoDB tables, you can get the size for data/individual indexes from `mysql.innodb_index_stats`. The 'size' stat contains the answer, in pages, so you have to multiply it by the page-size, [that is 16K by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_size).

```
select database_name, table_name, index_name, stat_value*@@innodb_page_size
from mysql.innodb_index_stats where stat_name='size';
```

The index PRIMARY is the data itself.

Comment: This assumes you have data in the table;  seems like the OP wants to estimate before populating.

Comment: could you elaborate on "The index PRIMARY is the data itself.", please? I thought that only accounted for the primary index size

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have data yet, here are some tips.  The following applies to InnoDB.  (MyISAM is much simpler, and smaller.)

Don't use `CHAR` for variable-length columns.  What `CHARACTER SET` are you using?  Ascii needs one byte per character; utf8mb4 needs between 1 and 4.

```
4 bytes per INT
35 for CHAR(35), if ascii or latin1; varchar is probably less
3 for the country code; it is fixed length
etc
```

Total = about 80 bytes.

Multiply the 80 by between 2 and 3 to account for various overheads.  Most likely the 1M row table will be between 160MB and 240MB.

To measure a single index, for say `CountryCode` of 3 bytes:

```
3 bytes data
4 bytes for the PK (implicitly included with any secondary key)
25 bytes basic overhead
32 total
times 1.5 -- overhead for BTree that was randomly inserted into
48MB -- total for 1M rows.
```

Notes:

- Only the leaf nodes (of BTrees) need to be computed; the overhead for the non-leaf nodes is *typically* 1%.
- The `PRIMARY KEY` is "clustered" with the data, so there is no need to compute it.
- If you do not have an explicit PK, then you need to add 6 bytes to the row size to allow for the fabricated PK.
- `ROW_FORMAT = COMPRESSED` gives you about a 2:1 shrinkage.  (This is not as good as typical zip (etc) compression rate of 3:1.)
- `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE "tablename";` is the quick way to compute the 'actual' size.  See `Data_length` for data and PK; `Index_length` for secondary indexes, and `Data_free` for some other stuff.
- It is rare for `Index_length` to exceed `Data_length`.  However it is not "wrong" for that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Table_NAME "tablename",
           data_length   "table data_length in Bytes",
           index_length  "table index_length in Bytes",
           data_free  "Free Space in Bytes"
    FROM  information_schema.TABLES  where  Table_schema = 'databasename';
```

by executing this query you can get size used for `Data` and `Index` of a table , You can check this size against # of rows and predict for 1 million rows

Comment: I am not sure but will this give some what accurate results ? have you tested this ever ?

Comment: Actually I am testing this query result periodically to see growth (%) w.r.t. size

Answer (score 0):

It's tedious. But the details are in [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-table-and-index.html#innodb-physical-record).

To be as accurate as possible, which is rarely necessary, you'll need to read about the table structure and index structure, too.

If I were in your shoes, I'd build the table, populate it with a million rows of test data, and measure the change in size. Depending on your application, you might need to take the size of transaction log files into account, too.