# When we are estimating the table size for mySQL table, why do we add primary key twice?

Tags: mysql

When we are estimating the table size for mySQL table, why do we add primary key size twice?
I saw this post [How to estimate/predict data size and index size of a table in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46069/how-to-estimate-predict-data-size-and-index-size-of-a-table-in-mysql?newreg=ad7f3fc30dcd43ff82a1611f54faa235) , and I noticed that the size of primary key is already in the row size.  Why do we add the primary key size again?

Comment: See [_this_](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/253041/1876) for a better estimate.

Answer (score 0):

> why do we add primary key twice?

This is an effect of InnoDB index structure.

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Clustered and Secondary Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html)

> All indexes other than the clustered index are known as secondary indexes. In InnoDB, each record in a secondary index contains the primary key columns for the row, as well as the columns specified for the secondary index.

In table structure shown in the thread there is 2 indices: primary (by `ID`) and secondary (by `CountryCode`). The PK expression value is included in both - explicitly in PK and implicitly in SI. It is described in [RolandoMySQLDBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/877/rolandomysqldba)'s [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46098/150107).

If there were three indexes in the table, the size of the primary index would be counted three times. 4 indexes - 4 times. And so on...

If no PK / UK in the structure then InnoDB adds inner 6-byte record number as a PK, and you must add `6 * (1 + indices count)` bytes to each record's indices storage size.